# How to pass token in headerfield using POST Method swift

Tags: swift

```
let tok = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaults.keys.setToken)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

request.setValue("token=\"\(tok)\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

> Error:["detail": Authentication credentials were not provided.]

Comment: request.addValue(access, forHTTPHeaderField: "accessToken")

Comment: i have stored "tokens" in userdefault

Comment: `if let tok = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaults.keys.setToken) {
            request.addValue(tok, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorisation")
        }`

Comment: header should be "Authorisation",cant pass token with header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in this way. It worked for me, 
Just pass your token to this function.....

```
    func SignupRequest(auth: String, mycomplete: @escaping (_ result: Data)->()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "URL HERE") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-VERSION")

    //X-API-AUTH-TOKEN
    request.setValue(auth, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-AUTH-TOKEN")

   let accessToken = "your access token"
   request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
                mycomplete((data as AnyObject) as! Data)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Happy Coding......

Comment: request.setValue("tok", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") i need to pass token to an API with "Authorisation " as Header

Comment: i got the same error ["detail": Authentication credentials were not provided.]

Comment: it is working, request.setValue("Token 0700755c6411ec927141", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") Got Response

Comment: Kindly accept the answer, so that it'll be useful for others. Thank you